# How to randomly permute some matrix into a bigger matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is the main matrix:

```
a =

 1     2     3     3     4     5     2     5     7
 3     4     5     5     6     8     6     4     9
```

This main matrix contain 3 small matrix. The first one is:

```
 [1 2 3;3 4 5]
```

The second one is:

```
 [3 4 5;5 6 8]
```

The third one is:

```
 [2 5 7;6 4 9]
```

I want to randomly permute these 3 matrix into the main matrix like this:

```
 a =

 2     5     7     3     4     5     1     2     3
 6     4     9     5     6     8     3     4     5
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you connect three 2D matrices, it is better to use a 3D matrix:

```
%get a 3d matrix
b=reshape(a,size(a,1),3,[]);
%randomly permute third dimension
c=b(:,:,randperm(size(b,3)));
%return to 2d representation
d=reshape(c,size(a));
```

Comment: You can also flatten the 3D matrix back to a 2D matrix like this: `d=c(:,:)`

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: how i can turn matrix (a) into 3D matrix?

Comment: The first line converts `a` into a 3d matrix. It changes the matrix dimensions from `[2 9]` to `[2 3 3]`.